# How to relate one model to 2 different models?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
user_details
    id - PK
    user_name
    user_email

cities
    id - PK
    city_name

regions
    id - PK
    region_name
    city_id - FK(cities)

user_region (Many to Many)
    user_id
    region_id
```

And these are the models:

User

```
public function regions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Regions', 'user_region', 'user_id', 'region_id');
}
```

Regions

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cities');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_region', 'region_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Cities

```
public function regions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Regions', 'city_id', 'id');
}
```

I need to get the city name for a user. Which relation can I use here to do this?

Comment: How can a user belong to many regions? How can a city belong to many regions? If both of these are the case, you won't be able to get 'the city name' for a user since they may have many.

Comment: A city can have many regions. And a user can work in many regions. But, the user will only work in a single city.

Comment: Edited my answer to well suit your situation, you can check and then respond.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> A city can have many regions. And a user can work in many regions. But, the user will only work in a single city.

As all regions which user belongs to will belong to only one city you can do as follow:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$city = $user->regions()->first()->cities;
echo $city->city_name;
```